# Is double or mutual composition a bad practice in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am coding some application and I wonder if is a bad practice to do double or mutual composition between two classes.

I have some code like this:

```php
class A {}
class B {}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->setBInstance($b);
$b->setAInstance($a);
```

Off course I know I'll have some semantic problems if I'll try to get some instance indiscriminately as follow:

```php
$a->getB()->getA() ...
```

But I really need double composition.

Comment: "But I really need double composition." It might help answer your question to explain **why**. Depending on what you're doing, there may be a better solution like dependency injection available, but it's hard to say from a contrived `A`/`B` example.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem to me